# Magento: Don't allow product to open without category url

Tags: magento

In our magento store we have one root category and one sub category in it.

We assigned 11 products to that sub category.

We created one CMS page which has same URL Key as one of our product's URL Key.

So when we try to open that CMS page it opens product page.

As a solution we think that all products must open with category URL only.

Without category URL it should give 404 or open CMS page if available.

How to achieve above functionality?

Please guide.

Comment: Why would you want to have a CMS page and a product page with the same url key? It doesn't make sense. Can you just use different for cms pages?

Comment: Actually we have two sites. One in wordpress and another in magento.
Now we want to migrate our wordpress site in magento.
So all pages of wordpress site will become CMS pages in magento.
And one of that page has same url key as product.
That's why we decide to open all products with category url only.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with your current situation.

If you need to give **same url key** to  **subcategory** and a **cms page** then you should change the **level of that subcategory to next level**.

Hope this helps